# Weird behavior of multiply in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use multiply in my program, but I find the behavior of this op is unnormal. It seems that it is calculating the wrong results. Minimum example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

batchSize = 2
maxSteps = 3
max_cluster_size = 4

x = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(dtype=tf.int32, maxval=20, shape=[batchSize, maxSteps, max_cluster_size]))

y = tf.sequence_mask(tf.random_uniform(minval=1, maxval=max_cluster_size-1, dtype=tf.int32, shape=[batchSize, maxSteps]), maxlen=max_cluster_size)

y = tf.cast(y, tf.int32)

z = tf.multiply(x, y)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    x_v = sess.run(x)
    y_v = sess.run(y)
    z_v = sess.run(z)

    print(x_v.shape)
    print(x_v)
    print('----------------------------')
    print(y_v.shape)
    print(y_v)
    print('----------------------------')
    print(z_v.shape)
    print(z_v)
    print('----------------------------')
```

Result:

```
(2, 3, 4)
[[[ 7 12 19  3]
  [10 18 15  7]
  [18  9  2  7]]

 [[ 4  5 16  1]
  [ 2 14 15 14]
  [ 5 18  8 18]]]
----------------------------
(2, 3, 4)
[[[1 1 0 0]
  [1 0 0 0]
  [1 1 0 0]]

 [[1 1 0 0]
  [1 1 0 0]
  [1 1 0 0]]]
----------------------------
(2, 3, 4)
[[[ 7 12  0  0]
  [10  0  0  0]
  [18  0  0  0]]

 [[ 4  5  0  0]
  [ 2  0  0  0]
  [ 5  0  0  0]]]
----------------------------
```

Where `z_v` is expected to be:

```
[[[ 7 12  0  0]
  [10  0  0  0]
  [18  9  0  0]]

 [[ 4  5  0  0]
  [ 2  14  0  0]
  [ 5  18  0  0]]]
```

When I test `multiply` in other programs, it goes just fine.
I suspect that this may be related to `x` and `y` are random variables. Anyone give a hint on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of these lines:

```
x_v = sess.run(x)
y_v = sess.run(y)
z_v = sess.run(z)
```

you need to use this:

```
x_v, y_v, z_v = sess.run( [ x, y, z ] )
```

With the first, separate version, basically what ends up happening is that you create x_v, and then y_v, but when you run the `sess.run(z)` it will recalculate z's dependencies as well, so you end up seeing the output from different x's and y's than you print.